# Using Unit Test For Android I faced This error: "Can't Create Handler inside Thread"

Tags: android, unit-testing

Using Android Unit Test JUnit4 I faced this error:

> Can't Create Handler Inside thread That has Not Called looper.prepare
>   ??

This Is My Test Class Thats Test Password Length:

```
public class ChangePasswordTest {
    private ChangePassword changePassword ;

@Before public void setUp() {
    changePassword = new ChangePassword();
}

@Test public void testValidPassword() {
    assertTrue(changePassword.validatePasswordExpression("validPassword1"));
}

@Test public void testShortPasswordReturnsFalse() {
    assertFalse(changePassword.validatePasswordExpression("Short"));
}

@Test public void testNullPasswordReturnsFalse() {
    assertFalse(changePassword.validatePasswordExpression(null));
}

@Test public void testLongPasswordReturnsFalse() {
    assertFalse(changePassword.validatePasswordExpression("ThisPasswordIsWayTooLongSoTrySomethingElse"));
}

@Test public void testEightCharPasswordReturnsTrue() {
    assertTrue(changePassword.validatePasswordExpression("IsValid1"));
}

@Test public void testNinteenCharPasswordReturnsTrue() {
    assertTrue(changePassword.validatePasswordExpression("ThisPasswordIsValid"));
}

@Test public void testTwentyCharPasswordReturnsFalse() {
    assertFalse(changePassword.validatePasswordExpression("ThisPasswordIsTwenty"));
}
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the entire stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

the exception message means that you are calling the code via a thread that has not prepared Looper. Normally it means you are not calling if from UI thread but you should - a normal thread does not prepare Looper, but UI thread always do.

So if you are trying to test a UI-Related component(And as i see you do). Try using Espresso:
https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/

Comment: I did not Test UI i make Function Unit Test                                           ..public static boolean validatePasswordExpression(String newPassword) {
        int passwordLength = newPassword.length();
        if (passwordLength > 20 || passwordLength < 8)
            return false;

        else return true;
    }

Comment: This is what the exception means anyway. Can you post the code you are testing ?